# Reading kml file

Tags: javascript, kml

i download a KML file..Is there any way to use javascript/php to loop through the file and get all the coordinates in the KML file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery ajax to read/loop the file. Just like normal XML.

More info for using jquery. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks! manage to use ajax jquery.. did not know that KML file can be read like nnormal XML..

Comment: Can you please share the code

Answer (score 0):

If the KML file is of a decent size, then it could be very worthwhile to first convert it to JSON (in PHP) before sending it to the user's browser.  JSON [will produce a lower filesize and also be faster to parse](http://www.navioo.com/ajax/ajax_json_xml_Benchmarking.php) (which could be of marginal benefit if the KML file is small, but very noticeable if it's complex).

```
// PHP:
$json = json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xml_string));
```

Comment: thanks fr ur input... but my KML file is rather huge in size, so decided to use jquery ajax :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to do similar to the OP. For data like this (from https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut):

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Placemark>
    <name>Simple placemark</name>
    <description>Attached to the ground. Intelligently places itself 
       at the height of the underlying terrain.</description>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-122.0822035425683,37.42228990140251,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
</kml>
```

I did this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

foreach($xml->Placemark as $Placemark){
    $name = $Placemark->name;
    echo $name."<br>";

    if ($Placemark->Point->coordinates == null) {
        continue;
    } else {
        $coordinates = explode(",", $Placemark->Point->coordinates);
        echo $coordinates[1].",".$coordinates[0]."<br>";
    }
}
```